# Best way to save and restore a DataTable c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, crash, restore

I have developed a `WinForm` c# application , now adding a recovery options so if it closes unexpectedly etc  Everything can be recovered on a new run.

I have managed to recover almost everything (list,Int,Strings etc...)
only issue i am facing is restoring a `DataTable`. During the run on my application records are added to this `DataTable` and at the end user can export this to csv.

I tried to add the `DataTable` to `Properties.Settings.Default`... But it does not work on the new run i always see it as `Null` .

Any suggestion on best way to save and restore a `DataTable` keeping in mind they records can go over 10-15 k during a run .

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Properties.Settings` can store string data, so you can serialize your `DataTable` and store it. Later you can deserialize the string to get `DataTable`. You can use [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) like:

```
var serializedDt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt);
//store the string
```

to retrieve back:

```
DataTable yourDataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(serializedDt);
```

One more thing to add, if you are expecting large data, then you may look at options to store data in a database at client side, like [Sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Comment: I have no prior experience with Json.. So please don't mind me asking. Wont it be a very long string? If there are 10k records in a DataTable and with approx 10 column and one of the column is Description which can contain very long text.

Comment: You can serialize your data in XML or JSON, [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) would be shorter than XML.

Comment: So you are saying it wont matter how long the string becomes it can be stored and retrieved using Properties.Settings

Comment: @confusedMind, you can try that yourself. I am not really sure how much data can be stored in settings. Since it stores data in a single file, so I believe it would depend on the OS requirement, but generally `Properties.Settings` is not a place to store that much data, you are better off using client side database like Sqlite etc.

Answer (score 1):

Serialze the object, but place it in a recovery file.  During recovery start just read the file, and you won't have to worry about space.

Comment: Can you please explain more about recovery file a link perhaps.

Comment: Yeah - when you open the DataTable just write it to a Text file in the ApplicationFolder, and then just read it on recovery startup. Maybe you write the name of the file to the settings.